# I want to get the shipping address id of an order from magento backend order

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

i tried this

```
$sales_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_order->getRealOrderId());
$billing_address_id = $sales_order->billing_address_id; 
$shipping_address_id = $sales_order->shipping_address_id;
```

This doesn't work on backend order.

Comment: I've never used Magento, but have you tried just dumping out the variable to see what's there with something like print_r( $sales_order ); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load the model using realOrderId() - use id instead I.e $_order->getId()

Where is this code you are working with? I assume that you are loading an order collection - you should be able to add the shipping_address_id attribute to the select so you don't have to reload the model. I.e...

$orderCollection->addAttributeToSelect('shipping_address_id');

Finally, personally I would use  getData() or the magic getters to retrieve properties on magento models depending on the specific situation I.e

getData('shipping_address_id')

Or

getShippingAddressId()